# Render Data in DetailsView(or GridView) Row SideBySide as Two Part or Two Column in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, detailsview

I am binding GridView And Then Opening Modal PopUp For Detailed View Of Selected Row.

My DetailsView Is As Below.

```
         <asp:DetailsView ID="DetailsView1" runat="server" CssClass="table table-bordered table-hover" 
                            BackColor="White" ForeColor="Black" FieldHeaderStyle-Wrap="false" FieldHeaderStyle-Font-Bold="true"
                            FieldHeaderStyle-BackColor="LavenderBlush" FieldHeaderStyle-ForeColor="Black"
                            BorderStyle="Groove" AutoGenerateRows="False">
                            <Fields>
                                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Date" DataField="Date" />
                                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Feeder Name" DataField="Feeder Name" />
                                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Meter Serial No" DataField="Meter Serial No" />
                                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Time" DataField="Time" Visible="false"/>
                                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Class Of Voltage" DataField="Class Of Voltage" />
                                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Voltage-R" DataField="Voltage-R" />
                                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Voltage-Y" DataField="Voltage-Y" />
                                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Voltage-B" DataField="Voltage-B" />
                                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Line Current-R" DataField="Line Current-R" />
                                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Line Current-Y" DataField="Line Current-Y" />
                                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Line Current-B" DataField="Line Current-B" />
                                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Neutral Current" DataField="Neutral Current" />
                                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Act. Power" DataField="Act. Power" />
                                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="React. Power" DataField="React. Power" />
                                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Act. Power(tot)" DataField="Act. Power(tot)" />
                                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="App. Power" DataField="App. Power" />
                                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="PF-R" DataField="PF-R" />
                                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="PF-Y" DataField="PF-Y" />
                                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="PF-B" DataField="PF-B" />
                                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Avg. PF" DataField="Avg. PF" />
                                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Freq." DataField="Freq." />
                                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Act. Import" DataField="Act. Import" />
                                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Act. Export" DataField="Act. Export" />
                                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Act. Import(F)" DataField="Act. Import(F)" />
                                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Act. Export(F)" DataField="Act. Export(F)" />
                                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Reactive(Q1)" DataField="Reactive(Q1)" />
                                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Reactive(Q2)" DataField="Reactive(Q2)" />
                                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Reactive(Q3)" DataField="Reactive(Q3)" />
                                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Reactive(Q4)" DataField="Reactive(Q4)" />
                                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Act. Import" DataField="Act. Import" />
                                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="App. Export" DataField="App. Export" />
                                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Cons. Act. Import" DataField="Cons. Act. Import" />
                                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Cons. Act. Export" DataField="Cons. Act. Export" />
                                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Act. Import Demand" DataField="Act. Import Demand" />
                                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Act. Export Demand" DataField="Act. Export Demand" />
                                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Cons. Act. Import(F)" DataField="Cons. Act. Import(F)" />
                                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Cons. Act. Export(F)" DataField="Cons. Act. Export(F)" />
                                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Cons. Reactive (Q1)" DataField="Cons. Reactive (Q1)" />
                                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Cons. Reactive (Q2)" DataField="Cons. Reactive (Q2)" />
                                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Cons. Reactive (Q3)" DataField="Cons. Reactive (Q3)" />
                                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Cons. Reactive (Q4)" DataField="Cons. Reactive (Q4)" />
                                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Cons. App. Import" DataField="Cons. App. Import" />
                                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Cons. App. Export" DataField="Cons. App. Export" />
                            </Fields>
                        </asp:DetailsView>
```

Here In Below How My DetailesView Render Data as Below.

[image]

The Problem Is As My Data Is Two Longer DetailedView Is Also Very Longer.
So I Here I want Idea That How Could I Render DetailsView Data SideBySide.

(Example:

**Now I am Getting DetailsView As Below**

1. A
2. B
3. C
4. D
5. E

**But I want To Render it As Below**

1.A   2.B

3.C   4.D

5.E

)

So, Can Anyone Give Me The Idea To Render DetailsView In This Way.

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: you can't manipulate bound fields that way. Although there are work arounds but that will make your code unnecessarily complex. why not use vertical scroll bar in the detail view?

Comment: one more thing.. is it that you are simply transposing the view? that is when you click on the details the same record is shown as two field records?

Comment: Yes Codeek.. The Same Record(Where(in which record) Button Click)  I see that In Details View. And I have Already Kept Vertical Scrollbar But the Requirement is To Do As Above.  Is There I can Create My Custom Control with More Column As I want to render my data. If Yes Then Please Just Help me with few steps that what i have to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry couldn't come online for past few days.
Use Repeater instead. That will do the job easily. You will have to use table,tr and td tags and the DataItem method to get your values as :

```
<asp:Repeater id="MyRptr" runat="server">
<HeaderTemplate>
<table border="1" width="100%">
<tr>
<th>Field</th>
<th>Value</th>
</tr>
</HeaderTemplate>

<ItemTemplate>
<tr>
<td>Date</td>
<td><%#Container.DataItem("Date")%></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Feeder Name</td>
<td><%#Container.DataItem("Feeder")%></td>
</tr>
....
<tr>
.....
</tr>
</ItemTemplate>

<FooterTemplate>
</table>
</FooterTemplate>

</asp:Repeater>
```

and set MyRptr's DataSource just like you do for gridview and then DataBind().

refer : [Repeater](http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/aspnet_repeater.asp)

Comment: ya thanks Codeek.. it is good and I can create design as I want using repeater.